# How to avoid segmentation fault with linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I would like to make a code that uses linked list, takes input from the terminal and then print a table out.

In this example, I am uploading some information from element table.

I get segmentation error.

Somebody can help me to understand why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct element{
    char name[20];
    char symbol[20];
    float atom_weight;
    struct Element* next;
} element;


/* Add a new node to the top of a list */
element* insert_top(char name[20], char symbol[20], float atom_weight, element* head) {
    element *new_element;
    new_element = (element *) malloc(sizeof(element));
    new_element->name[20] = name;
    new_element->symbol[20] = symbol;
    new_element->atom_weight = atom_weight;

    new_element->next= head;
    head = new_element;
    printf("Top inserted");
    return head;
}

element* table=NULL;
int main()
{
    int choice=1, i=0;
    char name[256];
    char symbol[256];
    float atom_weight;

    printf("%d", choice);
    while (choice!=0){

        printf("\n Please enter element name:");
        scanf("%s", name);

        printf("\n Please enter element symbol:");
        scanf("%s", symbol);

        printf("\n Please enter atomic weight:");
        scanf("%f", &atom_weight);


        //printf("%s, %s,...Weight %f",name, symbol, atom_weight);
        insert_top(name, symbol, atom_weight, table);

        i=i+1;
        printf("\nDo you want to continue (Y=1/N=0)? ");
        scanf("%d", &choice); //You should add the space before %c, not after

    }
    printf("Out of cycle\n");
    printf("Size of table %lu\n", sizeof(table));

    printf("Weight %f",table->atom_weight);


    while (table->next != NULL){
        printf("\nElement: %s \t\t Symbol: %s  \t\t Atomic weight: %f\n",table[i].name, table[i].symbol,table[i].atom_>
        //printf("ciao");
        table=table->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: A lot of things don't make sense here. You should carefully read the chapter on pointers and arrays in any given C textbook.

Comment: You never set value of `table` in `main()` to anything other than `NULL`. Given how you use it in the `while` loop at the end of `main()` I would expect a segfault there.

Comment: Also, given that you never increment `i` you can replace all `table[i]` with `table->` in that `while` loop at the bottom of `main()`.

Comment: What is the point of `temp` that you never initialize. I think you want to set it to `table` and then use `temp` instead of `table` inside the `while` loop.

Comment: C is case sensitive `Element` and `element` are not the same thing

Comment: Tip: Use `char*` as your go-to type for passing in generic C strings. Things like `char[20]` not only imply a limit that doesn't actually exist, but makes it much harder to change any such limits in the future. Notice that already you have a disconnect here: Your input type is `char[256]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy strings using strcpy, see `insert_top`
`Element` is not defined, should be `element`.
Minor don't cast malloc result.

There is still some issues, char size limitation, scanf return code to be checked.

you need to free the malloc memory at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct element{
    char name[20];
    char symbol[20];
    float atom_weight;
    struct element* next;
} element;


/* Add a new node to the top of a list */
element* insert_top(char name[20], char symbol[20], float atom_weight, element* head) {
    element *new_element = malloc(sizeof(element));
    strcpy(new_element->name, name);
    strcpy(new_element->symbol, symbol);
    new_element->atom_weight = atom_weight;

    new_element->next= head;
    printf("Top inserted");
    return new_element;
}

int main()
{
    element* table=NULL;
    int choice=1;

    printf("%d", choice);
    while (choice!=0){
        char name[256];
        char symbol[256];
        float atom_weight;

        printf("\n Please enter element name:");
        scanf("%s", name);

        printf("\n Please enter element symbol:");
        scanf("%s", symbol);

        printf("\n Please enter atomic weight:");
        scanf("%f", &atom_weight);


        //printf("%s, %s,...Weight %f",name, symbol, atom_weight);
        table = insert_top(name, symbol, atom_weight, table);

        printf("\nDo you want to continue (Y=1/N=0)? ");
        scanf("%d", &choice); //You should add the space before %c, not after

    }
    printf("Out of cycle\n");
    
    for (element *e = table; e; e = e->next) {
        printf("\nElement: %s \t\t Symbol: %s  \t\t Atomic weight: %f\n",
               e->name, e->symbol, e->atom_weight);
    }          
    return 0;  
}
```